# What are the use of buffer registers?

Tags: buffer

The image shows a buffer register as part of an SPI module

Why exactly is a buffer connected to the FIFO registers?

[image]

Comment: Presumably it is a transceiver, that is two back to back tri states?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a buffer in a way you might think about a buffer.

The SPIxBUF is the name for a IO special function register address that is used to write/read the data to/from FIFOs.

Comment: So essentially itds a memory controller?

Comment: What does it actually look like?

Comment: The actual implementation is irrelevant. It is a bunch of logic gates that can be abstracted as per the block diagram to provide you a high level understanding how the SPI peripheral works - i.e. you use SPIxBUF name in your code to read and write data.

Comment: I believe the implementation is not irrelevant, the diagram provides high level details of functionality. Without the implementation you would essentially have to force relations, there may also be further requirements not listed in the high level representaiton which can be derived form the implementaiton itself

Comment: So an example implementation is always best for providing understanding

Comment: Surely a microcontroller register reference manual, datasheet, or errata would describe all requirements to use the SPI peripheral or nobody would be able to use it correctly. What matters is that it works and people can write software to operate it. Again how it is actually implemented internally in the hardware is irrelevant, and most likely it is parametrically synthesized by a tool from high level HDL code anyway.

Comment: Agree to disagree but thank you

Comment: Sure, we can disagree. May I ask why do you think it is important to know how a MCU feature is implemented and what difference does it make for you as a person using the MCU? And at what level it is important; transistor level, gate level? Anyway, no microcontroller vendor gives out details you are after, they simply give out all information necessary to use the features of the MCU, including the quirks.